# Bitbake, build from git but not latest commit

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake

I have a bitbake recipe which will fetch the latest commit from branch develop, however; I want to build from older commit to try some things out.

I made a new branch which i commited the code i wanted to build to, but this is not really a practical or long term solution.

This is the code from my .bb file :

```
SRC_URI = "git://xxxxxxxx.com:1337/Customer/webtool;protocol=ssh;branch=develop \                                                                                                                      
           file://webyyy.py \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
           file://webzzz.service \                                                                                                                                                                         
"                                                                                                                                                                                                           
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
```

(removed some information about the project)

Is it possible to do this without commiting the code i wanna build to another branch?

Comment: Just put the correct commit hash in `SRCREV` ?

Comment: @JDB please post your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by [Nayfe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6225741/nayfe) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58132965/bitbake-build-from-git-but-not-latest-commit?noredirect=1#comment102652876_58132965):

> Just put the correct commit hash in `SRCREV`?

The OP indicated that this [answer was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58132965/bitbake-build-from-git-but-not-latest-commit?noredirect=1#comment102653108_58132965):

> Worked like a charm, thanks!